# Why does my transmission-clie torrrent download not work?

Tags: transmission

I read about `transmission-cli` and wanted to use it but I could not find out why my downloads did not work and I was wondering if it was set up the right way. I also had problems with authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is install it with

```
 sudo apt install transmission-cli transmission-daemon transmission-common
```

You can start the background process with `transmission-daemon --no-auth` and check if it works with `transmission-remote -l`. This should print an empty list of currently active torrents.

Note that this is insecure because you run it without authentication so everybody in the network could use the background process. But it is just for testing at this point.

You can add a torrent with `-a`, for example with the current Ubuntu image:

```
 transmission-remote -a https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.10/ubuntu-20.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent?_ga=2.98476063.1086280564.1605774166-1450607686.1605774166
```

If you check again with `transmission-remote -l` you will see the added link in the list. After a while the status should change from *Idle* to *Downloading*.

If you dont want to seed you can change the upload limits in the configuration file to `0` and set `upload limit enabled` to `true`. To change this configuration you have to `sudo systemctl stop transmission-daemon` before you edit it or the content will be overwritten. Start it again after editing with `sudo systemctl. start transmission-daemon`.

If your torrent client is working you can now start configuring it more accurately with the advice from here: https://www.smarthomebeginner.com/install-transmission-web-interface-on-ubuntu-1204/

---

### Troubleshooting:

The service is in

```
/lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service
```

I had to delete the following intermediate files to make the program load the current `settings.json`:

```
 sudo rm -R /var/lib/transmission-daemon
```